# iOS TableView with dynamic data and background picture loading

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a view controller with a three segmented button at the top, and below it a table view. When the user clicks a button, a URL is called, and the appropriate data is loaded into the cells. Then, the appropriate images are loaded in the background and the tableview is updated. The issue lies when the user clicks a different button AND the images from the last set of data haven't finished loading. Initially I prevented the user from clicking a different button, until all of the first data was done loading. But this was really slow. Then I tried waiting until all the images were done being loaded before updating the tableview, but that is also pretty slow. Is there a better way of doing this besides making three tableviews? Below is how I get images.

```
- (void) getImageLinks:(int)number{
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[imageLinks objectAtIndex:number]];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:@{@"User-Agent": @"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25"}];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if([data length] > 0){
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        if(image){
            [images addObject:image];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if(number<[imageLinks count]-1){
                    [self getImageLinks:number+1];
                }else{
                    isRefreshing = NO;
                    _segmentedControl.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                    NSLog(@"end refreshing");
                    [_tableView reloadData];
                    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
                }
            });
        }else{
            NSLog(@"NO IMAGE");
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: btwn where is your souce code??

Comment: Updated to show source code.

Comment: you can use dictionary to handle three button click on segment. first store data in dictionary with any key and add this dictionary in main array and on click get this dictionary from this and load. When first time you request for data get from server at that time also give tag that request so that in background you can get all data.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used background Queue for Requesting data. Just Call the request to the URL in Background queue and save the Image data. Then You can Synchronously call the Image to update to ImageView in Main queue using dispatch_sync() method.

Comment: Requesting data isn't the issue. Updating the table is.